# Parsing and saving the rows of excel file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, xlsx

Have an excel file with a column with some text in each row of this column.

I'm using pandas `pd.read_excel()` to open this .xlsx file. Then I would like to do the following: I would like to save every row of this column as a distinct .txt file (that would have the text from this row inside this file). Is it possible to be done via pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the basic idea would be to use an iterator to loop over the rows, `open`ing a each file and writing the value in, something like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
for i, value in enumerate(df['column']):
  with open(f'row-{i}.txt', 'w') as fd:
    fd.write(value)
```